# Convert Java Map to Object

Tags: java, object, dictionary, hashmap, testng

I have the Java Method `getStatusAndAnnotation` in `TestListener` class as below:

```
public void getStatusAndAnnotation(ITestResult result) { 
        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Method method = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
        Annotation annotation = TestListener.class.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);

        int status = 0;
        try {
            TestInfo testinfo = (TestInfo) annotation;
            if (annotation!=null) {
                for (String testId: testinfo.id()) {
                    map.put("id",testId.substring(1));

                    switch (status) {
                    case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.PASSED.getValue());
                    case ITestResult.FAILURE:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.AUTO_FAIL.getValue());
                    default:
                        map.put("result", STATUS.UNTESTED.getValue());
                    }

                        ResultCollector.addTestResult(map);   
                }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            TestLogger.logInfo("Failed to find the annotation and the status of the test " + method);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here what I am doing is getting the Java TestNG method, its annotation and the status of the tests such as Pass, Fail, etc. Putting them in map one by one as you can see in code above - calls of `map.put("id",testId.substring(1));` and

`map.put("result", STATUS.UNTESTED.getValue());`

Finally I am calling the method `addTestResult()` method from my ResultCollector class that will hold all these maps.

However, I see people `suggesting me to create an object rather than directly putting in map as I am just storing 2 values - id and status for each test.`

How do I use object instead of map and what is the better way in Java to accomplish this?

Comment: Do they not mean to create an object that wraps `id` and `status` and put that into the map, instead of putting `id` and `status` into the map. That's how I read their suggestion.

Comment: Yeah they mean to create the object that wraps id and status and put that in map, finding a good way to do this here.

Comment: Can someone guide me to achieve the object that can wrap id and status in my case and put that in map? ***Edited - as Johny posted below.

Comment: Looking at your code, I see that your call to `map.put(...)` has `"id"` as the first parameter, every time. Do you know how maps work?

Comment: Yeah I put id for every test first and then the status for it. I do this for every test and send the map.

Comment: Can anyone help me in guidance on this?

Comment: This is not how a map was designed to be used. The first parameter of `Map#put` is known as the key, the second is know as the value. Each key is mapped to its associated value. Repeatedly calling `Map#put` with the same key effectively overwrites that key's associated value. In your code, you repeatedly call `Map#put` with either `"id"` or `"result"`, effectively overwriting those key's associated values.

Comment: I get you - what could be better solution then? Only map is what I know a little bit of.

Comment: You should read [this book](http://dept.cs.williams.edu/~bailey/JavaStructures/Book_files/JavaStructures.pdf).